# Allow the sub-domaine in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I used htaccess login / password to secure my site, when I want to enter the directory of my site I type login / password, it works perfectly, the problem that when I enter with a sub-domain, it asks me to enter again  LOG/PASS.
i need to fix this issue, any idea
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's because a different subdomain would be considered a different website, so you need to authenticate again.